# Converting From String to INT saves another value

Tags: c#, oop

I have one function in which i take the numbers as string and when i convert the numbers to int they are saved with some other value.
Why is that Please help.

```
private string DoTheMath()
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] s1 = s.Split(' ');

    int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1[0]);
    int k1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1[1]);
}
```

when i input 49 51 
int n1 gets value 31
and int k1 gets value 33

Comment: Try using decimals instead

Comment: How do you check the numbers?

Comment: Breakpoints as i am adding them.

Comment: Can you print them into debug instead?

Comment: Sounds like you've got your debugger reporting values in hex and just haven't noticed it. Hint: try entering 15 16 and see what you get. I suspect you'll see F and 10.

Comment: Since you have debugged your code, what was the elements of `s1` ?

Comment: Seems like its hexadecimal value that you're seeing in your debugger.

Comment: Okay now i get it the debugger must be showing hexa decimals value.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are parsing strings to ints, you probably want Int32.Parse:

```
private string DoTheMath()
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] s1 = s.Split(' ');

    int n1 = Int32.Parse(s1[0]); 
    int k1 = Int32.Parse(s1[1]);
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` calls `Int32.Parse`. He won't get any different results by calling `Int32.Parse`.